# Show Price Suffix only on all WooCommerce Product loops

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have an online shop with WooCommerce. I want to show a custom price Suffix only on the Product List Page (like Shop Page), where all products are listed.

I have the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
    $price = $price . ' Suffix '; 
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

But with this code, the suffix is display in the Product list Page and on single Products. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide your site URL? This can be achieved by simple CSS.

Comment: Make use of [Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/). - `is_shop()` - Returns true when on the product archive page (shop).

Comment: Thank for your answer. How do I have to insert the  is_shop()  function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will show an additional custom price suffix on all product listings *(except on single products)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'additional_price_suffix', 999, 4 );
function additional_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Not on single products
    if ( ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && ! empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) || ! is_product() ) {
        $html .= ' ' . __('Suffix');
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Or you can also use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'additional_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
function additional_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Not on single products
    if ( ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && ! empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) || ! is_product() ) {
        $price .= ' ' . __('Suffix');
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: on the front page its still not working. The code i posted in the beginning is working on all pages perfectly. Can you change this code, that the single product page is excluded?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can use the `is_shop()` function to check if you are on the shop page like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    if ( is_shop() ) $price .= ' ' . __('Suffix');
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is only working in the shop page, but not in the category pages

Comment: That is correct. Your original question only asked about the shop page. The answer of @LoicTheAztec should do the trick.