# Show a price suffix only on all WooCommerce single products

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using *[Show Price Suffix only on all WooCommerce Product loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922063/show-price-suffix-only-on-all-woocommerce-product-loops/62922978#62922978)* answer code to my previous question, to display a price suffix after the price on all pages except the Product Detail Page (WooCommerce).

I want to have another price suffix only for the Product Detail Page.
The suffix should include a link and the font size should be editable.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a price suffix on single products only with a custom link, try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'additional_single_product_price_suffix', 999, 4 );
function additional_single_product_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Not on single products
    if ( ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) ) {
        // Define below the link for your price suffix
        $link = home_url( "/somelink.html" );

        $html .= ' <a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank" class="price-suffix">' . __('Suffix 2') . '</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Inline CSS style rules *(can be added instead to the theme's styles.ccs file)*:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'product_price_suffix_css_styling_rules', 9999 );
function product_price_suffix_css_styling_rules() {
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() ):
    ?><style>
        a.price-suffix, a.price-suffix:visited {font-size: 13px; color: #DC143C;}
        a.price-suffix:hover, a.price-suffix:active {color: #960404}
    </style><?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If the price suffix should include a link inside the text, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'additional_single_product_price_suffix', 999, 4 );
function additional_single_product_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Not on single products
    if ( ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) ) {
        // Define below the link for your price suffix
        $link = home_url( "/somelink.html" );

        $html .= sprintf( ' <span class="price-suffix">' . __('Suffix %s') . '</span>', '<a href="' . $link . '"  target="_blank">' . __("link") . '</a>');
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Inline CSS style rules *(can be added instead to the theme's styles.ccs file)*:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'product_price_suffix_css_styling_rules', 9999 );
function product_price_suffix_css_styling_rules() {
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() ):
    ?><style>
        span.price-suffix {font-size: 13px; color: #000000;}
        span.price-suffix > a, span.price-suffix > a:visited {color: #DC143C}
        span.price-suffix > a:hover, span.price-suffix > a:active {color: #960404}
    </style><?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: thanks its working, but the link should open in a new tab. And how can I change the font size of the link?

Comment: Yes I mean new window. And I want to change the font size of the text and link. can you help me please?

Comment: Its working perfect, can you just add something that I can change the color of the link? That would be nice

Comment: its working, can you just add a hover color for the link then its perfect